# Why should we use aysntask or service instead of a new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, process, android-asynctask, android-service

In android why should we use a asyntask and service, instead of using a new thread() and write the necessary background functionality?

I know that we should not run long running operations like downloading a file from server on the mainthread aka UI thread. And should use a asynctask or service.

But why cant we create a new thread() {which is eventually a new thread other than the main thread} and write necessarily long running operation in that thread.

why did google create the AsyncTask and Service without suggesting to use the regular New Thread()???

thanks in advance

edit1:
may be i wasn't clear in my question or not sure, if i am, even now. help me out.

i get it, the whole point starts from

```
Do not block the UI thread
Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread
```

why ?
1.how much can the UI thread handle ? how can we determine a breakpoint? how is a ANR point determined? can we track?
2. when a service component handles long running operations why can't a activity component handle?

**Remember that if you do use a service, it still runs in your application's main thread by default, so you should still create a new thread within the service if it performs intensive or blocking operations**
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
the above statement is from android documentation.

3.why cant a service start in a new thread straight away, if we are so concerned about main thread? don't get me wrong in question 3, i am trying to understand the advantage of starting the service in main thread. by default.

in the above statement , does it suggest the main thread's ability to start and handle a service's long running operation load? if so does it contradict with question 1.

Comment: It makes everything a whole lot easier.

Comment: service is totally unrelated. it cannot replace or be replaced by a thread. they perform completely different things. AsyncTask is a wrapper around Thread+Scheduler+runOnUiThread.

Comment: Better read up on **[Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)** in Android, which should answer your question.

Comment: thanks guys, @MH wouldnt have found the link without ur help :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well let's look how you'd perform a simple task using a Thread.

The first step is to create a Thread using a Runnable. Something like this:

```
private void fetchResultsAsync() {
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<String> results = fetchResultsFromWebServer();
        }
    };
    new Thread(runner).run();
}
```

The thing is, we need to show the results so it would actually be more like this:

```
private void fetchResultsAsync() {
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<String> results = fetchResultsFromWebServer();
            workFinished(results);
        }
    };
    new Thread(runner).run();
}
private void workFinished(List<String> results) {
    // show the results on the UI
}
```

It looks good, but there's a problem; the callback method (workFinished) has to update the UI. If we do this from any non-main thread, there will be big problems. We need a thread-safe way to call that method, which is what Handlers are for. Let's also throw in a method for updating our progress, which is very common. The code would now look like this:

```
private final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
private void fetchResultsAsync() {
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<String> results = fetchResultsFromWebServer();
            workFinished(results);
        }
    };
    new Thread(runner).run();
}
private void showProgress(int result) {
    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update a progress bar here
        }
    });
}
private void workFinished(final List<String> results) {
    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // show the results on the UI
        }
   });
}
```

Compare this to the implementation using an AsyncTask:

```
private void fetchWithTask() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<String>>() {

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return fetchResultsFromWebServer();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
            // show the results on the UI
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // update a progress bar here
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

It doesn't differ much by lines of code, but it's much more obvious what needs to happen and where. It protects you from nasty mistakes like forgetting to wrap UI-touching code in a Runnable that has to be posted to a UI-Thread-owned Handler.

Now imagine that you have several different types of small background tasks that need to be performed. It would be very easy to call the wrong showProgress or workFinished method from the wrong background Thread because you have to plug all those pieces together yourself.

There's also a very nasty bug lurking in the use of Handler's default constructor. If the containing class is first referenced by a non-UI thread during runtime, the Handler would belong to that Thread. AsyncTask hides always does things on the correct Thread. This is hard to catch!

At first blush AsyncTasks don't seem all that useful, but the callback plumbing is where they *really* pay off in spades.

Comment: hey @Krylez thanks for the explanation. I understand the whole Asynctask concept. thanks though for the detailed explanation. i tried to vote u up but i need some 15 min reputation.

Answer (score 1):

"instead of using a new thread() and write the necessary background functionality?"

Why rewrite the background functionality? AsyncTask does it for you. As njk2 mentioned a Service is not really a fair comparison, though IntentService automatically creates a new thread for you in onHandleIntent().

edit: To answer your other questions, blocking the UI thread, will block all user interaction and the app will appear to "freeze". Definitely not something we want to do at all.